# What traits should I look for to know if an .exe is vulnerable to buffer overflow or format string?

Tags: c, format, buffer, overflow, exe

I am doing an exercise as part of learning about something called buffer overflow in the C programming language (supposedly a classic).

I learned that with buffer overflows in memory, a program can be made to do unintended things because of the way the actual memory works. First, I have an .exe file to play with. How do I begin to look at it, with what program? And then, what do I look for to sense these overflow / format string susceptible traits?

Thanks for helping me learn. It's been a while since doing something quite this mind-wracking...

Comment: Usually you play with the input: overlong input strings, overlong environment variables, integer over/underflows, embed format specifiers like %s or %n in input strings, etc. pp. This question is OT, however.

Comment: A disassembler can help you view the assembly code to give you a sense of the memory during the attack. I recommend gdb. Here's a good resource on a linux environment: https://www.exploit-db.com/docs/28475.pdf

Comment: gdb is a debugger, not really a disassembler although it could be used for that, regardless, he mentioned .exe which implies Windows, not Linux. For windows you can use windbg as a debugger to see how your program runs and IDA Pro Free edition to disassemble.